# How to install package from launchpad

Tags: ubuntu

I would like to install this in my ubuntu: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ttfautohint

but I don't know how.

I did `sudo apt install ttfautohint` and ttfautohint --version gives 0.97.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I'm able to do it (in 2022):

Given a launchpad url: `https://launchpad.net/~fish-shell/+archive/ubuntu/release-3/+packages` -- in this case, for fish shell.

I can extract two components:

- the user `fish-shell` (prefixed by `~`)
- the release channel `release-3`

Then the command to add the repository:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fish-shell/release-3`.

Apt will confirm, and then run `apt update` automatically. If the package is already installed but out of date, `apt autoremove` to clean the slate and `apt install` to get the most recent release.

---

If you don't know the release channel, or can't derive it from the launchpad url, just do without and apt will give you some options:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fish-shell

Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~fish-shell/ubuntu/ppa'.
The team named '~fish-shell' has no PPA named 'ubuntu/ppa'
Please choose from the following available PPAs:
 * 'beta-2':  fish shell - 2.x beta series
 * 'beta-3':  fish shell - 3.x beta series
 * 'nightly-master':  fish shell - nightly build from git master
 * 'release-2':  fish shell - 2.x release series
 * 'release-3':  fish shell - 3.x release series
```

---

If you can't sort out the team name, here's what it looks like when you get it wrong:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu/fish-shell
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~ubuntu/ubuntu/fish-shell'.
ERROR: '~ubuntu' user or team does not exist.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to upgrade the version, you must first remove the package from your system:

`$ sudo apt-get remove ttfautohint`

After making sure that the package is removed, do a:

`$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu/ttfautohint`

It'll ask for your confirmation and verification of the GPG signed key. This will add the desired ppa to your sources file, and make it visible. Then, you must do a:

`$ sudo apt-get update`

For it to see the changed package location. Then you can simply install it as you've just typed, with apt-get:

`$ sudo apt-get install ttfautohint --verbose-versions`

The '--verbose-versions' will show you what version will be installed, and you can check if the desired version is being installed.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore: ```$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu/ttfautohint
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~ubuntu/ubuntu/ttfautohint'.
ERROR: '~ubuntu' user or team does not exist.
```

Comment: This answer likely isn't needed anymore because Ubuntu now has that package directly onto the source, so you don't need to add it as a PPA anymore. Have you tried with an updated ubuntu (18.04+), just to install it directly? Which versions do you need? @AlekseyKontsevich

Comment: @Yuri-M-Dias I need git-cola 3.9, Ubuntu 20.04 has only outdated and buggy 3.6. Forced to [install manually](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/git-cola/+question/695751). So in my case it was not a PPA.

Comment: Even though this particulate package might have moved to the main Ubuntu repository, the answer is still rather helpfulfor those learning PPA. Adding "+1" to the answer.